# How does a column of zeros in a matrix influence its right singular vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

Here is the SVD decomposition calculated in Julia:

[image]

---

Why is the 4th column of $V^{T}$ also zero? How is that connected with columns of $A$?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: No need for a print-screen. Embedding code is easy and, more importantly, code is searchable.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you , I will be careful next time!

Comment: Why next time? You can still edit your question! People looking for `julia>` would find it.

Comment: The print-screen weighs some 260 KB. Times 23 views so far, that is some 5 MB. Come on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $A$ has singular value decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^T$, then the columns of $V$ (the rows of $V^T$) form a basis for the row space of $A$. Because every row of $A$ is orthogonal to $(0,0,0,1,0)$, this must hold for the columns of $V$ as well.

Equivalently, the nullspace of $V^T$ must be equal to the nullspace of $A$, and the nullspace of $A$ contains the vector $(0,0,0,1,0)$.

Comment: Great, this is precisely what I've been looking for. Thank you so much!